# dpkg -l shows only a few installed packages after crash

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, synaptic

`dpkg -l` shows only a tiny subset of actually installed packages (Ubuntu 22.04).

Is there a way to recreate the list of installed packages?

Background:

This happend after trying to install vinagre. The install crashed and left not fully installed and or configured packages.
While resolving the problem via a rescue system it seems that the database of installed packages was overwritten.

The vinagre crash corrupted some packages like python3, systemd, systemd-timesyncd which I reinstalled. It seems that only these reinstalled packages are listed with `dpkg -l`.

Therefore I don't get any updates for most of the actually installed packages with `apt update` any more.

If there is no way to restore the list of packages, I could recreate the list of installed packages by reinstalling them all.

Is there maybe a scanner which loops over the available packages and searches for their files on the local system?

Or is there a list of packages which are commonly installed? openSuSE's YAST for example has patterns which are groups of packages to install eg. base, Laptop, Network and Server

I know that if everything fails I could click through all packages in Synaptic and guess what might have been installed, but I'm not very keen on doing so.

EDIT: What I did to resolve the issue:

First I had to do the messy part from the accepted answer.
I found that `/var/backups/dpkg.status.0` was almost 4 weeks old, even though I update packages nearly every day. I think the status was from before I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 (from 21.10). I used Meld to merge `/var/lib/dpkg/status` with `/var/backups/dpkg.status.0`, keeping the newer entries and adding the older ones.

After that I tried the neat part.
`sudo dpkg --verify` came up with a lot of complaints about missing packages which I tried to `apt install` and if they were not found removed with `apt remove`.
Finally I did a `sudo apt update` and updated 1000+ packages.

I'll see if that helps, but at least `/var/lib/dpkg/status` seems to reflect the current system better than before.

@raffa's hint with `/var/backups/dpkg.status.0` was really helpful. Thank you for your help.

Comment: In such case `sudo dpkg --configure -a` needs to be run.

Comment: If not resolved then `sudo dpkg --verify` or even `sudo dpkg --audit`  should be run in that order.

Comment: if you are lucky you can use `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old`

Comment: I'm not lucky. `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old` contains the same as dpkg -l returns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The neat part

> If there is no way to restore the list of packages, I could recreate
> the list of installed packages by reinstalling them all.

There are multiple copies/backups(automatic) of the `dpkg` status/database.

> Is there maybe a scanner which loops over the available packages and
> searches for their files on the local system?

There is a more efficient log file at `/var/log/dpkg.log` that contains packages ever handled by `dpkg` along with their status and if you filter that file with like `grep “install”` you get a list of all the packages installed by `dpkg`.

> Or is there a list of packages which are commonly installed?
> openSuSE's YAST for example has patterns which are groups of packages
> to install eg. base, Laptop, Network and Server

Yes, one meta package `ubuntu-desktop`.

> I know that if everything fails I could click through all packages in
> Synaptic and guess what might have been installed, but I'm not very
> keen on doing so.

No need for that, there are `dpkg` options to fix database corruption.

> Is there a way to recreate the list of installed packages?

(you mean verify/check as the database/files are still there) Yes,in most corruption cases.

You need to, first, run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then, run:

```
sudo dpkg --verify
```

then, run:

```
sudo dpkg --audit
```

finally, run:

```
sudo apt update
```

From [man `dpkg`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/dpkg.1.html):

> **--configure** package...|-a|--pending    Configure a package which has been unpacked but not yet configured.  If -a or    --pending is
> given instead of package, all unpacked but unconfigured packages are
> configured.
>
> **-V, --verify** [package-name...]    Verifies the integrity of package-name or all packages if omitted, by comparing    information
> from the files installed by a package with the files metadata
> information    stored in the dpkg database (since dpkg 1.17.2).  The
> origin of the files metadata    information in the database is the
> binary packages themselves. That metadata gets    collected at package
> unpack time during the installation process.
>
> Currently the only functional check performed is an md5sum
> verification of the file    contents against the stored value in the
> files database.  It will only get checked if    the database contains
> the file md5sum. To check for any missing metadata in the    database,
> the --audit command can be used.
>
> **-C, --audit** [package-name...]    Performs database sanity and consistency checks for package-name or all packages if    omitted (per
> package checks since dpkg 1.17.10).  For example, searches for
> packages    that have been installed only partially on your system or
> that have missing, wrong or    obsolete control data or files. dpkg
> will suggest what to do with them to get them    fixed.

---

#### The messy part

Last resort, if the above didn't work, then the `dpkg` database(status) is seriously damaged beyond repair or even empty or missing. In this situation first backup whatever you have if any like so:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/my-old-status
```

Then, try restoring from `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old` like so:

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

That file holds a near recent copy(around one day old).

If that was not successful, then look under `/var/backups/` like so:

```
ls -lh /var/backups/ | grep status
```

Start by restoring the most recent one `dpkg.status.0` like so:

```
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Then see how things go and if needed restore older backups(these are compressed `.gz` files so extract/decompress them first) one by one until things are back to normal(no errors when running `sudo apt update`)

Please, notice as well that other related files are also backed up and might be restored as well if restoring `status` alone is not enough to resolve the issue. You can list them with:

```
ls -lh /var/backups/ | grep dpkg
```

To know what you are missing, here are the files and directories that normally live under `/var/lib/dpkg/`:

```
$ ls -lh /var/lib/dpkg/
total 5.4M
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jun 11 12:41 alternatives
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   11 Jan  8 02:35 arch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 178K Aug 19  2021 available
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8 Aug 19  2021 cmethopt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  616 Jan  8 02:38 diversions
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  671 Jan  8 02:38 diversions-old
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 436K Jun 16 10:54 info
-rw-r----- 1 root root    0 Jun 16 14:36 lock
-rw-r----- 1 root root    0 Jun 16 14:36 lock-frontend
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Mar 23  2020 parts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  270 Jan  8 13:40 statoverride
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  309 Jan  8 13:40 statoverride-old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.4M Jun 16 10:54 status
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.4M Jun 16 10:54 status-old
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jun 11 12:40 triggers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jun 16 14:36 updates
```

---

#### The dirty part

If you get here, you are most likely out of ideas/choices and on the verge of committing a fresh Ubuntu install ... Let's reach an agreement **first**; I don't know you and you don't know me (**you are totally on your own**) ... This is a dirty business(yours) and you should deal with it alone :) ... The process ahead will parse the contents of `/var/log/dpkg.log`(*assuming you haven't blown up this one yet*) into package names and feed them to `apt` for re-installation ... This should rebuild your `dpkg` status/database even if it is severely damaged(which it is) ...  **If you have other choices, please take them now** ... "no other choices" ... let's get to business:

- Run all the four commands in the neat part above, one by one and in the same order (**again**).
- Reinstall the supposedly(*assuming you did not install then remove a package/s*) installed/half-installed packages by parsing the contents of `/var/log/dpkg.log` into package names and feeding them to `apt install -y` like so(*This is working but, not optimal ... I strongly urge you to improve it if you ca*n):

  ```
  awk -F' |:' '/installed/ { if ( !seen[$7]++ ) print $7 }' /var/log/dpkg.log | xargs sudo apt install -y
  ```
- Deal with errors(*oh yeah, there will be errors)*, fix them and start over until all packages are installed with no errors ... Good luck(you're gonna need it).

Comment: Unfortunately that did only help a bit. Some packages show up now (120) but there a still a lot missing. For example kernel, grub are still missing in list.

Comment: @Arigion Please  run `sudo apt update` afterwords then try `dpkg -l` again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. `sudo apt update` returns that all packages are up to date. Furthermore when I try to install an already installed package I get a huge list of additional packages to install.

Comment: @Arigion Then the database is not just corrupt ... its damaged ... updating answer with more instructions ... one moment please.

Comment: @Arigion "when I try to install an already installed package I get a huge list of additional packages to install." ... That might be a good thing(dependencies) as your last resort ... Just use the `--reinstall` flag when reinstalling preexisting package ... the huge list is based on calculations with your current `dpkg` database/list ... they will be reinstalled and added to the list hopefully once and for all.

Comment: I accepted your answer and edited my question with what I actually did. Thanks.