# dpkg-query: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 0: end of file after field name ' '

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I am getting this dpkg error when trying to launch a dpkg command:

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 0:
end of file after field name ''
```

When trying to update `apt-get update` i get this:

```
Hit:1 http://download.hiveos.farm/repo/binary  InRelease 
Hit:2 http://download2.hiveos.farm/repo/binary  InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/h-realh/roxterm/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:4 https://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable bionic InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/dpkg/status (1)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted
```

Some help would be kindly appreciated !

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1414284

Comment: @Raffa thank you, you're a saviour

Comment: You are most welcome ... I am glad it helped :-)